# intersects sprite and get currentTarget

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript

I have create a few sprites consist of various music notes, when the cursor sprite move over to one of the notes, it would blink using intersect. I have no idea on how to make the cursor detect which note it overlap. Can anyone provide an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
getObjectsUnderPoint(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY);
```

or

```
for each (var spr:Sprite in notes) {
  if (spr.hitTestPoint (stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY)) {
     // some code here
  }
}
```

These documentation pages might help: [getObjectsUnderPoint](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getObjectsUnderPoint%28%29), [hitTestPoint](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestPoint%28%29)

Comment: Can it be use for UIComponent? I added each sprite into a UIComponent before add them to stage in FB4

Comment: UIComponent inherits both DisplayObjectContainer and DisplayObject, so yes, it will work.

Comment: Strange, I try  trace(cursorStick.getObjectsUnderPoint(new Point(cursorStick.x,cursorStick.y)));  and the note under that does not show any trace on the FB console, does the point have to be accurate to the note xy position?

Comment: It has to be the position relative to the main stage (use `localToGlobal`, if necessary), and it has to be within the boundary box of the note.  Also, `getObjectsUnderPoint` only returns items in the display list, which might be Sprites and Shapes BELONGING to the note, instead of the note itself.

Comment: yes, I could only get the shape. What do you suggest to create a boundary box for each notes? Appreciate.

Comment: Each Sprite automatically has a boundary box.  You could go up in the display list (call the shape's parent, parent.parent, etc.) until you get the note object, but you should consider using the other approach (for each), as this gets very ugly.

Comment: Ok, since I have array of all the notes position, I would use that approach instead. Sprite appear to be of shape, but not box and I try to capture from my mouse, it only return Stage properties. I still welcome you to provide a simple tutorial if there a better alternative like box collision.